# Running totals in PHP and HTML using SQL

Tags: php, html, sql

I am working on a website using PHP and I am currently having difficulty getting a running total. When someone enters a number to order it should display a total to the right. I have been stuck on this for months. Can someone please help?

I have it so it automatically gathers the data from the SQL files, but I want it to be able to do totals while the user is putting in numbers.

I am unsure of how to phrase this better.

Below is the code I have for the Order page, please let me know what is needed to help make this easier to understand.

Thanks!

```
<?php 
  session_start();
  $pageName="Order";
  require_once("header.php");
  require_once("serverCode/checklogin.php");
  require_once("serverCode/connect.php"); 
?>

<h2>Order Quantity</h2>
<!--Contact information-->
<form method='post'>
  <h3>Contact Information:</h3>   
    <div id="errorMessage" class='errorMessage' style="color:white;"></div>
<div>    
  <div class='formInput percent50'>First name:<br>
  <?php echo "<input type='text' name='txtFirstName' id='txtFirstName' value='" . $_SESSION['userFirstName'] ."'>"; ?></div>

  <div class='formInput percent50'>Last name:<br>
  <?php echo "<input type='text' name='txtLastName' id='txtLastName' value='" . $_SESSION['userLastName'] ."'>"; ?></div>

  <div class='formInput percent100'>Address:<br>
  <?php echo "<input type='text' name='txtAddress' id='txtAddress' value='" . $_SESSION['userAddress'] ."'>"; ?></div>

  <div class='formInput percent50'>City:<br>
  <?php echo "<input type='text' name='txtCity' id='txtCity' value='" . $_SESSION['userCity'] ."'>"; ?></div>

  <div class='formInput percent50'>Postal Code:<br>
  <?php echo "<input type='text' name='txtPostalCode' id='txtPostalCode' value='" . $_SESSION['userPostalCode'] ."'>"; ?></div>

  <div class='formInput percent100'>Email:<br>
  <?php echo "<input type='text' name='txtEmail' id='txtEmail' value='" . $_SESSION['userEmail'] ."'>"; ?></div>
</div>

  <div class='formInput percent100'>Notes:<br>
  <?php echo "<input type='text' name='txtNotes' id='txtNotes' value='" . 'notes' ."'>"; ?></div>
</div>

<?php
//Create a table to fill in
  echo("<table border=1>");
  echo("<tr><th>Image</th><th>Name</th><th>Product Description</th>    <th>Cost</th>    <th>Order</th><th>Total</th></tr>");
  require_once("serverCode/connect.php");
  $sql = "Select * FROM products;";

  $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // jQuery associate number with the textbox for each product
    //dynamic on the fly (after is simpler )
    $id = $row['productsID'];
    $productsName = $row['productsName'];
    $productsDesc = $row['productsDesc'];
    $productsCost = $row['productsCost'];
    $productQty = $productQty;
    echo("<tr>");
    echo("<td>" . "<img src='images/" . $id . ".jpg'"    . "</td>");
    echo("<td>" . $productsName . "</td>");
    echo("<td>" . $productsDesc . "</td>");
    echo("<td>" . $productsCost . "</td>");
    echo("<td><input type=number>" . $productQty.  "</td>");
    echo("<td>" . $productsCost * $productQty . "</td>");
    //display a running total
    echo("</tr>");
    }
  echo("</table>")      
?>
  <script src="clientCode\validate.js"></script>
  </form>

<div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit Order">
    </div>
<?php require_once("footer.php"); ?>
```

Comment: Use Ajax? With Ajax you can change html content without reloading the page. This way when user write something, you can send the data to a php OR get some data from php then use the result to display somehting using jQuery

Comment: you will need to add some javascript or jquery code to update the html content on user inputs without refreshing the whole page.

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of running total? Do you want to show price of each product based on quantity user has entered in the input box? This is what you are referring to as 'running total'.

Comment: use java-script and jquery. Also,if you are maintaining stock in database then use ajax with jquery and javacript

Comment: try Jquery onblur="getTotal()". The getTotal() will have the logic for calculating the total.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to also check the input value to make sure it's a valid number.